# How to create a new categorical variable based on the location of first zero in a column in a long format data using R?

Tags: r

The data set is lay out in long format and doesn't have missing value, which has 5 columns,
the 1st column is "id",
the 2nd column is "gender",
the 3rd column is a binary variable "competency",
the 4th variable is salary,
and the 5th column is time.

Now, I want to create a new categorical variable "yeel"(year-end evaluation level") by id based on the following rules,

1-if all values of "competency" variable equal 1 within each id, then the value of "yeel" should be "unqualfied";

2-if the location of 1st zero in the variable "competency" falls into the range [1,5] of the "time" variable, then the value of "yeel" should be "entry level";

3-if the location of 1st zero in the variable "competency" falls into the range [6,8] of the "time" variable, then the value of "yeel" should be "intermediate level";

4-if the location of 1st zero in the variable "competency" falls into the range [9,12] of the "time" variable, then the value of "yeel" should be "senior level";

5-if all values of "competency" variable equal 0 within each id, then the value of "yeel" should be "undefined";

For example, the expected data set should look like as follows

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14), gender = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), competency = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), salary = c(15000, 
15500, 15800, 16000, 16200, 16400, 16600, 16800, 17000, 17300, 
17500, 17500, 15000, 16000, 17000, 18000, 19000, 20000, 21000, 
22000, 23000, 24000, 25000, 26000, 15000, 16000, 18000, 20000, 
22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000, 34000, 36000, 15000, 
16000, 17000, 17500, 18000, 18500, 19000, 19500, 20000, 20500, 
21000, 21500, 15000, 15300, 15600, 15900, 16200, 16500, 16800, 
17100, 17400, 17700, 18000, 18300, 15000, 15500, 15800, 16000, 
16200, 16400, 16600, 16800, 17000, 17300, 17500, 17500, 15000, 
16000, 17000, 18000, 19000, 20000, 21000, 22000, 23000, 24000, 
25000, 26000, 15000, 16000, 18000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 26000, 
28000, 30000, 32000, 34000, 36000, 15000, 16000, 17000, 17500, 
18000, 18500, 19000, 19500, 20000, 20500, 21000, 21500, 15000, 
15300, 15600, 15900, 16200, 16500, 16800, 17100, 17400, 17700, 
18000, 18300, 15000, 15500, 15800, 16000, 16200, 16400, 16600, 
16800, 17000, 17300, 17500, 17500, 15000, 16000, 17000, 18000, 
19000, 20000, 21000, 22000, 23000, 24000, 25000, 26000, 15000, 
16000, 18000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000, 
34000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 
36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000), time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), yeel = c("unqualified", "unqualified", 
"unqualified", "unqualified", "unqualified", "unqualified", "unqualified", 
"unqualified", "unqualified", "unqualified", "unqualified", "unqualified", 
"entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", 
"entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", 
"entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", 
"entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", 
"entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", 
"entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", 
"entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", 
"entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", "entry level", 
"entry level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "intermediate level", "intermediate level", 
"intermediate level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "senior level", "senior level", "senior level", 
"senior level", "undefined", "undefined", "undefined", "undefined", 
"undefined", "undefined", "undefined", "undefined", "undefined", 
"undefined", "undefined", "undefined")), row.names = c(NA, 168L
), class = "data.frame")->df_new
```

The original data set is structured as follows,

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14), gender = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), competency = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), salary = c(15000, 
15500, 15800, 16000, 16200, 16400, 16600, 16800, 17000, 17300, 
17500, 17500, 15000, 16000, 17000, 18000, 19000, 20000, 21000, 
22000, 23000, 24000, 25000, 26000, 15000, 16000, 18000, 20000, 
22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000, 34000, 36000, 15000, 
16000, 17000, 17500, 18000, 18500, 19000, 19500, 20000, 20500, 
21000, 21500, 15000, 15300, 15600, 15900, 16200, 16500, 16800, 
17100, 17400, 17700, 18000, 18300, 15000, 15500, 15800, 16000, 
16200, 16400, 16600, 16800, 17000, 17300, 17500, 17500, 15000, 
16000, 17000, 18000, 19000, 20000, 21000, 22000, 23000, 24000, 
25000, 26000, 15000, 16000, 18000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 26000, 
28000, 30000, 32000, 34000, 36000, 15000, 16000, 17000, 17500, 
18000, 18500, 19000, 19500, 20000, 20500, 21000, 21500, 15000, 
15300, 15600, 15900, 16200, 16500, 16800, 17100, 17400, 17700, 
18000, 18300, 15000, 15500, 15800, 16000, 16200, 16400, 16600, 
16800, 17000, 17300, 17500, 17500, 15000, 16000, 17000, 18000, 
19000, 20000, 21000, 22000, 23000, 24000, 25000, 26000, 15000, 
16000, 18000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000, 
34000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 
36000, 36000, 36000, 36000, 36000), time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)), row.names = c(NA, 168L), class = "data.frame")->df

Thank you for your help!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `case_when` to pass multiple conditions for each `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(first_zero_loc = time[match(0, competency)], 
          yeel = case_when(all(competency == 1) ~ "unqualfied", 
                           all(competency == 0) ~ "undefined",
                           between(first_zero_loc, 1, 5) ~ "entry level", 
                           between(first_zero_loc, 6, 8) ~ "intermediate level",
                           between(first_zero_loc, 9, 12) ~ "competency level",
                          ))  %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-first_zero_loc)
```